# ASP.NET 5 error after upgrading from Beta-6 to Beta-7

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am creating an ASP.NET 5 web app. I have the following packages installed:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta6"
  },
```

when I update these packages to

```
 "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta7-14368",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta7-12113",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta7-12488",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta7-12221"
  },
```

I get the following error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Method not found: 'Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Library Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.ILibraryManager.GetLibraryInformation(System.String)'.

Comment: Is beta7 out yet? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/6.0.0-beta1

Comment: I am installing the packages from MyGet  https://www.myget.org/gallery/aspnetvnext. Here are the details for package:  Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc v6.0.0-beta7-14368 11 hours ago

Comment: Looks like the latest version is 12275 instead of 14368, maybe try upgrading to that?

Comment: I have configured nuget package manager to get packages from MyGet which hosts latest build of packages. Seems like the nightly version I am using, have some build errors. I am using an old version now and everything works fine. Thanks for help :)

Comment: try once by using beta7-*

Answer (score 1):

It may relate to [Runtime refactoring in Beta7](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/45)
and [Build and IntelliSense issues in VS2015 RTM with Beta7 DNXes](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/44)